# What permissions are needed to prevent a group from writing to or deleting a file?

Tags: chmod

`myfile` permissions:  group has rwx

`mydir` permissions: group has rwx

Problem: user1 wants to prevent group members from writing to `myfile` or deleting `myfile`

What `chmod` options are needed  to achieve user1's aim?

Comment: Not that it changes anything, but it's probably "myfile", not "mylife".

Comment: yes it's "myfile" and what is the answer of my question

Comment: @simranjitkaur who owns the file? What is `mydir` and how is it connected to `myfile`? What operating system are you using? What did you try and how did it fail so we don't repeat your work?

Comment: https://ictteach.its.utas.edu.au

Comment: i have a fully picture of my question but its not send in this question section.

Answer (score 1):

Question is not entirely clear. Assuming that you are asking that given a file "myfile" within a folder "mydir" with the following permissions / owners:

```
$ ls -acl mydir/
total 4
drwxrwx---.  2 user1 group1  60 Mar 24 04:13 .
drwxrwx---. 15 user1      user1   300 Mar 24 04:14 ..
-rwxrwx---.  1 user1 group1   5 Mar 24 04:13 myfile
```

And you are asking what needs to be done so that the group can access and read the file but not write to or delete the file, then

```
chmod g-w mydir
chmod g-w mydir/myfile
```

Now, it might seem at first glance that only `chmod g-w mydir/myfile` would be needed. And if you only wanted to prevent writing, this would be enough. But if a user in the same group attempts to delete the file, they will be prompted to confirm they wish to delete a write-protected file but not prevented from doing so because they have write permissions for the directory as well. Thus the directory would also need to remove the write permissions for the group.

This, of course, will not keep `root` or users in the `sudo` / `wheel` groups from being able to delete the file; it only will restrict normal users and group members.